# rotate and resize the image view with single finger in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app which has feature that resizing and rotating the imageview by dragging its bottom right corner button.

I saw one app which has feature that if we drag the bottom right corner button diagonally imageview size had resized or else if we drag the button left or right side direction imageview had rotated as per direction. I wish to implement this feature in my app

I am struggling to implement single finger rotation as well as resizing the imageview.

Please guide me in right way.[image]

---

I am trying this code, and try to apply zoom and rotate but not able to do please help me.
belove code to do zoom and rotate finger base action.

```
public class ScaleActivity extends Activity {

ViewGroup lLayout;
static ImageView img, backgrndImg;
Canvas mCanvas;
float d;
private float mAspectQuotient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLayout);

    final CropView cv = new CropView(this);
    lLayout.addView(cv);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class CropView extends ImageView {
    private static final int SELECTION_RECT_PAINT_COLOR = 0xFF000000;
    private static final int SELECTION_RECT_FILL_COLOR = 0x70FFFFFF;
    private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 25;
    private static final int xInc = 25;
    private static final int yInc = 25;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int initial_size = 200;
    private Point leftTop, rightBottom, center, previous, currentPoint,
            rectPos;
    private Paint fillPaint;
    private Paint rectPaint;
    protected Rect selection, dest;
    private boolean isAffectedBottom = false;
    Bitmap bitmap, backgroundBitmap;
    Rect rectf;
    Rect knobRect;
    private Context mContext;
    int width, height;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Bitmap resizedBitmap;

    // Adding parent class constructors
    public CropView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mContext = context;

        backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                .getResources(), R.drawable.toast_bkgrd);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.aviary_adjust_knob);

        rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        rectPaint.setColor(SELECTION_RECT_PAINT_COLOR);
        fillPaint = new Paint();
        fillPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        fillPaint.setColor(SELECTION_RECT_FILL_COLOR);
        currentPoint = new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        width = backgroundBitmap.getWidth();
        height = backgroundBitmap.getHeight();
        initCropView();
    }

    public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        initCropView();
    }

    public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initCropView();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mCanvas = canvas;
        if (leftTop.equals(0, 0))
            resetPoints();
        mCanvas.save();
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0,
                backgroundBitmap.getWidth(), backgroundBitmap.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
        // mCanvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, matrix, rectPaint);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, null, selection, rectPaint);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, selection.right - 25,
                selection.bottom - 25, null);
        rectPos.set(selection.left, selection.top);

        mCanvas.restore();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            previous.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            if (isActionInsideRectangle(event.getX(), event.getY())
                    && !isAffectedBottom) {
                drag((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                invalidate(); // redraw rectangle
                previous.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            }
            previous.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            previous = new Point();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initCropView() {
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        leftTop = new Point();
        rightBottom = new Point();
        center = new Point();
        previous = new Point();
        rectPos = new Point();

    }

    public void resetPoints() {
        center.set(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        leftTop.set((getWidth() - initial_size) / 2,
                (getHeight() - initial_size) / 2);
        rightBottom.set(leftTop.x + initial_size, leftTop.y + initial_size);
        selection = new Rect(leftTop.x, leftTop.y, rightBottom.x,
                rightBottom.y);
        knobRect = new Rect(selection.right, selection.bottom,
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        dest = selection;
    }

    private boolean isActionInsideRectangle(float x, float y) {
        int buffer = 10;
        return (x >= (selection.left) && x <= (selection.right)
                && y >= (selection.top) && y <= (selection.bottom)) ? true
                : false;
    }

    void touchDown(int x, int y) {

        System.out.println("selection " + selection);
        int dx = (previous.x - x) / 2;
        int dy = (previous.y - y) / 2;
        // d= rotation(dx,dy);
        currentPoint.set(x, y);
        if (pointsAreClose(x, y, selection.right, selection.bottom)) {
            isAffectedBottom = true;
            System.out.println("isAffectedBottom " + isAffectedBottom);
        }
    }

    void touchMove(int x, int y) {
        currentPoint.set(x, y);
        if (isAffectedBottom) {
            int dx = (previous.x - x) / 2;
            int dy = (previous.y - y) / 2;
            double startAngle = getAngle(previous.x, previous.y);

            double currentAngle = getAngle(x, y);

            matrix.postRotate((float) (startAngle - currentAngle),
                    selection.width() / 2.0f, selection.height() / 2.0f);
            // selection.inset(dx, dy);             
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    void touchUp(int x, int y) {
        currentPoint.set(x, y);
        isAffectedBottom = false;
    }

    private boolean pointsAreClose(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        return Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2) < TOUCH_TOLERANCE;
    }

    private void drag(int x, int y) {
        int movement;
        movement = x - previous.x;
        int movementY = y - previous.y;
        selection.set(selection.left + movement, selection.top + movementY,
                selection.right + movement, selection.bottom + movementY);
        selection.sort();
        invalidate();
    }


    /**
     * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
     * 
     * @param event
     * @return Degrees
     */
    // private float rotation(float dx, float dy) {
    //
    // // double delta_x = (dx);
    // // double delta_y = (dy);
    // double radians = Math.atan2((selection.left) - (previous.y),
    // (selection.top) - (previous.x));
    // double radians2 = Math.atan2((selection.left) - (dy),
    // (selection.top) - (dx));
    //
    // System.out.println("radians" + radians);
    // System.out.println("" + radians2);
    // System.out.println("radians2-radians" + (radians2 - radians));
    // System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(radians2 - radians));
    // return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians2 - radians);
    //
    // }

    private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
        double x = xTouch - (getWidth() / 2d);
        double y = getHeight() - yTouch - (getHeight() / 2d);

        switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            System.out.println("32");
            return 180 - (Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);

        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

        default:
            // ignore, does not happen
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return The selected quadrant.
     */
    private int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
        if (x >= 0) {
            return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
        } else {
            return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Checkout the Sony Android app developers site. http://developer.sonymobile.com/tag/one-finger-zoom/

Answer (score 10):

I have Design A Layout that may work as your need.
Download Demo [here](http://ravikoradiya.com/android/StickerDemo/StickerDemo.zip)

Java File

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ClipArt extends RelativeLayout {
    int baseh;
    int basew;
    int basex;
    int basey;
    ImageButton btndel;
    ImageButton btnrot;
    ImageButton btnscl;
    RelativeLayout clip;
    Context cntx;
    boolean freeze = false;
    int h;
    int i;
    ImageView image;
    String imageUri;
    boolean isShadow;
    int iv;
    RelativeLayout layBg;
    RelativeLayout layGroup;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    public LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int margl;
    int margt;
    float opacity = 1.0F;
    Bitmap originalBitmap;
    int pivx;
    int pivy;
    int pos;
    Bitmap shadowBitmap;
    float startDegree;
    String[] v;

    public ClipArt(Context paramContext) {
        super(paramContext);
        cntx = paramContext;
        layGroup = this;

        basex = 0;
        basey = 0;
        pivx = 0;
        pivy = 0;

        mInflater = ((LayoutInflater) paramContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater"));
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.clipart, this, true);
        btndel = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.del));
        btnrot = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rotate));
        btnscl = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sacle));

        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);
        layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        image = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clipart));
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ClipArt.this.cntx,
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent paramAnonymous2MotionEvent) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        layGroup.invalidate();
                        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                        layGroup.performClick();
                        basex = ((int) (event.getRawX() - layoutParams.leftMargin));
                        basey = ((int) (event.getRawY() - layoutParams.topMargin));
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int i = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int j = (int) event.getRawY();
                        layBg = ((RelativeLayout) getParent());
                        if ((i - basex > -(layGroup.getWidth() * 2 / 3))
                                && (i - basex < layBg.getWidth() - layGroup.getWidth() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = (i - basex);
                        }
                        if ((j - basey > -(layGroup.getHeight() * 2 / 3))
                                && (j - basey < layBg.getHeight() - layGroup.getHeight() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = (j - basey);
                        }
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -1000;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -1000;
                        layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        this.btnscl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    int j = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int i = (int) event.getRawY();
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layGroup.getLayoutParams();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.invalidate();
                        ClipArt.this.basex = j;
                        ClipArt.this.basey = i;
                        ClipArt.this.basew = ClipArt.this.layGroup.getWidth();
                        ClipArt.this.baseh = ClipArt.this.layGroup.getHeight();
                        int[] loaction = new int[2];
                        layGroup.getLocationOnScreen(loaction);
                        margl = layoutParams.leftMargin;
                        margt = layoutParams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        float f2 = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(i - ClipArt.this.basey, j - ClipArt.this.basex));
                        float f1 = f2;
                        if (f2 < 0.0F) {
                            f1 = f2 + 360.0F;
                        }
                        j -= ClipArt.this.basex;
                        int k = i - ClipArt.this.basey;
                        i = (int) (Math.sqrt(j * j + k * k)
                                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(f1 - ClipArt.this.layGroup.getRotation())));
                        j = (int) (Math.sqrt(i * i + k * k)
                                * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(f1 - ClipArt.this.layGroup.getRotation())));
                        k = i * 2 + ClipArt.this.basew;
                        int m = j * 2 + ClipArt.this.baseh;
                        if (k > 150) {
                            layoutParams.width = k;
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = (ClipArt.this.margl - i);
                        }
                        if (m > 150) {
                            layoutParams.height = m;
                            layoutParams.topMargin = (ClipArt.this.margt - j);
                        }
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.performLongClick();
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;

                }
                return ClipArt.this.freeze;
            }
        });
        this.btnrot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
            public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ClipArt.this.layGroup.getLayoutParams();
                    ClipArt.this.layBg = ((RelativeLayout) ClipArt.this.getParent());
                    int[] arrayOfInt = new int[2];
                    layBg.getLocationOnScreen(arrayOfInt);
                    int i = (int) event.getRawX() - arrayOfInt[0];
                    int j = (int) event.getRawY() - arrayOfInt[1];
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.invalidate();
                        ClipArt.this.startDegree = layGroup.getRotation();
                        ClipArt.this.pivx = (layoutParams.leftMargin + ClipArt.this.getWidth() / 2);
                        ClipArt.this.pivy = (layoutParams.topMargin + ClipArt.this.getHeight() / 2);
                        ClipArt.this.basex = (i - ClipArt.this.pivx);
                        ClipArt.this.basey = (ClipArt.this.pivy - j);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int k = ClipArt.this.pivx;
                        int m = ClipArt.this.pivy;
                        j = (int) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ClipArt.this.basey, ClipArt.this.basex))
                                - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m - j, i - k)));
                        i = j;
                        if (j < 0) {
                            i = j + 360;
                        }
                        ClipArt.this.layGroup.setRotation((ClipArt.this.startDegree + i) % 360.0F);
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return ClipArt.this.freeze;
            }
        });
        this.btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                if (!ClipArt.this.freeze) {
                    layBg = ((RelativeLayout) ClipArt.this.getParent());
                    layBg.performClick();
                    layBg.removeView(ClipArt.this.layGroup);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void disableAll() {
        this.btndel.setVisibility(4);
        this.btnrot.setVisibility(4);
        this.btnscl.setVisibility(4);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setFreeze(boolean paramBoolean) {
        this.freeze = paramBoolean;
    }
}
```

Layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rotate" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/rotation"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/sacle" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/pointer"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/del" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:src="@drawable/close"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/clipart" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and images put in drawable

[image]   [image]   [image]

Comment: now how to apply pinch-zoom of this ClipArt via fingers (muti-touch) not single finger???

Comment: @Attaullah its only for single touch, you need to implement it.

Comment: Dear @RBK i know this its only for single touch, but how to implement multi touch, actually i need zoom function on this ClipArt please??

Comment: Great work, any idea how can we use scale function on all 4 corners?

Comment: Thanks, @Shrikant 
for Scale from all four corner, you need to do some calculations and resize the view accordingly.

Comment: Yeah! But it would be great if let us all know what calculations have you used for left bottom scale.

Comment: how to drag from other corner of the image? 
If i drag from bottom left, then the top right position should be fixed

Comment: output of this is good, but the variables used in this is not understandable, and there is no comments to read what is going on, specially in btnscl.ontouch

Comment: The Best Answer, that I found while searching this. 
If you want to do the scaling diagonally (same to height as to width), the do these changes


k = j * 2 + ClipArt.this.basew;
int m = j * 2 + ClipArt.this.baseh;
if (k > 150) {
 layoutParams.width = k;
 layoutParams.leftMargin = (ClipArt.this.margl - j);
}

if (m > 150) {
 layoutParams.height = m;
 layoutParams.topMargin = (ClipArt.this.margt - j);
}


This way, you can increase/decrease your height, as the same amount, your width in increases/decreases.

Answer (score 8):

please check the repository in github i create it .

count the distance from center point in the rotate and zoom view  to the push point.
just use :

```
 private float getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
    float v = ((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x)) + ((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
    return ((int) (Math.sqrt(v) * 100)) / 100f;
}
```

and count the OA/OB that value can count the view new height and width

count the angle AOB, the A is the first push point , the B is the last move point ,the O is the center of the View Point .

and then  just set new height and width for view ,and count the left and top for view .

souce link : https://github.com/ryanch741/android-view-rotate-zoom-single-finger

the code:

```
    Point pushPoint;
int lastImgWidth;
int lastImgHeight;
int lastImgLeft;
int lastImgTop;
int lastImgAngle;
double lastComAngle;

int pushImgWidth;
int pushImgHeight;

int lastPushBtnLeft;
int lastPushBtnTop;

private View mView;
private Point mViewCenter;
private static final double PI = 3.14159265359;

public PushBtnTouchListener(View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;
}

private FrameLayout.LayoutParams pushBtnLP;
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams imgLP;
float lastX = -1;
float lastY = -1;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View pushView, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        // 主点按下
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            pushBtnLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) pushView.getLayoutParams();
            imgLP = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();

            pushPoint = getPushPoint(pushBtnLP, event);
            lastImgWidth = imgLP.width;
            lastImgHeight = imgLP.height;
            lastImgLeft = imgLP.leftMargin;
            lastImgTop = imgLP.topMargin;
            lastImgAngle = (int) mView.getRotation();

            lastPushBtnLeft = pushBtnLP.leftMargin;
            lastPushBtnTop = pushBtnLP.topMargin;

            pushImgWidth = pushBtnLP.width;
            pushImgHeight = pushBtnLP.height;
            lastX = event.getRawX();
            lastY = event.getRawY();
            refreshImageCenter();
            break;
        // 副点按下
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float rawX = event.getRawX();
            float rawY = event.getRawY();
            if (lastX != -1) {
                if (Math.abs(rawX - lastX) < 5 && Math.abs(rawY - lastY) < 5) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            lastX = rawX;
            lastY = rawY;

            Point O = mViewCenter, A = pushPoint, B = getPushPoint(pushBtnLP, event);
            float dOA = getDistance(O, A);
            float dOB = getDistance(O, B);
            float f = dOB / dOA;

            int newWidth = (int) (lastImgWidth * f);
            int newHeight = (int) (lastImgHeight * f);


            imgLP.leftMargin = lastImgLeft - ((newWidth - lastImgWidth) / 2);
            imgLP.topMargin = lastImgTop - ((newHeight - lastImgHeight) / 2);
            imgLP.width = newWidth;
            imgLP.height = newHeight;
            mView.setLayoutParams(imgLP);

            float fz = (((A.x - O.x) * (B.x - O.x)) + ((A.y - O.y) * (B.y - O.y)));
            float fm = dOA * dOB;
            double comAngle = (180 * Math.acos(fz / fm) / PI);
            if (Double.isNaN(comAngle)) {
                comAngle = (lastComAngle < 90 || lastComAngle > 270) ? 0 : 180;
            } else if ((B.y - O.y) * (A.x - O.x) < (A.y - O.y) * (B.x - O.x)) {
                comAngle = 360 - comAngle;
            }
            lastComAngle = comAngle;

            float angle = (float) (lastImgAngle + comAngle);
            angle = angle % 360;
            mView.setRotation(angle);
            Point imageRB = new Point(mView.getLeft() + mView.getWidth(), mView.getTop() + mView.getHeight());
            Point anglePoint = getAnglePoint(O, imageRB, angle);

            pushBtnLP.leftMargin = (int) (anglePoint.x - pushImgWidth / 2);
            pushBtnLP.topMargin = (int) (anglePoint.y - pushImgHeight / 2);
            pushView.setLayoutParams(pushBtnLP);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

private void refreshImageCenter() {
    int x = mView.getLeft() + mView.getWidth() / 2;
    int y = mView.getTop() + mView.getHeight() / 2;
    mViewCenter = new Point(x, y);
}


private Point getPushPoint(FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp, MotionEvent event) {
    return new Point(lp.leftMargin + (int) event.getX(), lp.topMargin + (int) event.getY());
}

private float getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
    float v = ((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x)) + ((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
    return ((int) (Math.sqrt(v) * 100)) / 100f;
}

private Point getAnglePoint(Point O, Point A, float angle) {
    int x, y;
    float dOA = getDistance(O, A);
    double p1 = angle * PI / 180f;
    double p2 = Math.acos((A.x - O.x) / dOA);
    x = (int) (O.x + dOA * Math.cos(p1 + p2));

    double p3 = Math.acos((A.x - O.x) / dOA);
    y = (int) (O.y + dOA * Math.sin(p1 + p3));
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot... after wasting so much time in coding i got your solution working perfectly as i needed... A huge thanks again. :)

Comment: now how to apply pinch-zoom of this ClipArt via fingers (muti-touch) not single finger???

Comment: how to implement on simple imageview without SingleFigureView?

Comment: Thanks a ton man, it's working like charm. God bless you !

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the rotation/scaling happens from the image center? In that case, it's simple trigonometry to find the rotation angle and the size:

[image: Diagram of triangle formed between picture center and finger]

Calculate `dx` and `dy` of the finger's coordinates minus the center coordinates. `Math.atan2(dy, dx)` is the rotation angle (in radians) and `Math.hypot(dx,dy)` can be used for the relative size, or just double the dx/dy and use directly.

Comment: Did you see the Sony Mobile link posted by Simon above?

Comment: ya am refer this code but not able to do zoom and rotate same time .its not smooth.

Comment: am try to applay one bitmat ,that bitmap applay matrix and matrix.postscale.that bit map give canvas.drawbitmap and applay rect ,that rect applay scale its currect way.please help me

Comment: You might want to update your question above with this information: what have you tried, what is going wrong? Or you could start a new thread with specific questions and you might get some better help.