# Single finger scale and rotate on canvas bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to Android and working on a project. I want to know about How to do single finger rotate and scale on canvas bitmap. Like as the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271430/rotate-and-resize-the-image-view-with-single-finger-in-android). please help and post your idea/code.

Comment: Thanks Rosalie. You have any idea. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you refer below link, it may be help you

1. for rotate - http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/07/21/rotating-a-bitmap-in-android/
2. for scale - http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/

Comment: @Dantalian I think. They are removed it. If I saw any other sample, I'll post here.