# Rotate layout containing a sticker based on onTouchListener in android

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation

I have been trying for more than a week now, but I am not able to rotate the layout(Relative) properly based on the touch. I need to set the angle of rotation such that the layout rotates as I move the finger on the left bottom of the layout (which has a small image). Basically I am having a Relative layout which has a sticker image. I am able to drag and zoom the sticker(Image) by touching the respective corner of the layout but I am not able to rotate it properly. Can somebody help me to set the angle of rotation so that the whole layout can be rotated smoothly?

here is the code snippet

```
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                lastTouchedScaleXPosition = event.getX();
                lastTouchedScaleYPosition = event.getY();

                if(previousXPosition == 0 && previousYPosition == 0){

                    int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
                    v.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
                    previousXPosition= viewLocation[0];
                    previousYPosition= viewLocation[1];

                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                currentTouchedXPosition = event.getX() - lastTouchedScaleXPosition;
                currentTouchedYPosition = event.getY() - lastTouchedScaleYPosition;

                currentXPosition = previousXPosition + currentTouchedXPosition;
                currentYPosition = previousYPosition + currentTouchedYPosition;


                RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
                int w =  mainLayout.getWidth();
                int h =  mainLayout.getHeight();

                float center_x = 0;
                float center_y = 0;
                center_x +=  w/2;
                center_y +=  h/2;

                double tx = currentXPosition - center_x, ty = currentYPosition - center_y;
                double t_length = Math.sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);
                double a = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(ty / t_length));

                mainLayout.setRotation((float) a);

                mainLayout.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
                mainLayout.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = w;
                lp.width =  h;

                parent.setLayoutParams(lp);


                previousXPosition = currentXPosition;
                previousYPosition = currentYPosition;

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`

Comment: where/ how do you initialize 'lastTouchedXPosition'? In the 'case ...ACTION_DOWN' part I can only see 'lastTouchedScaleXPosition'

Comment: sorry for the confusion its lastTouchedScaleXPosition and lastTouchedScaleYPosition only

Comment: Meanwhile I am basically able to detect counter-clockwise rotation as well. BUT even though I used an AsyncTask I can't get rid of the flickering and the rotation detection is not reliable. So I'll delete my answer because I'm not satisfied with half a solution.

Comment: Is there any better way for calculating the angle of rotation?

Comment: the maths part seems to be straightforward but Java is not the fastest language and you do a lot of calculating every time the user moves the finger. PLUS the repainting for the animation. I'm sure I can't do it, but I'd like to know a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried many things but didnot get the desired result.This link helped me to solve the issue.
[rotate and resize the image view with single finger in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271430/rotate-and-resize-the-image-view-with-single-finger-in-android)

Source link https://github.com/ryanch741/android-view-rotate-zoom-single-finger